# Problems creating foreign keys in MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a foreign key as follows:

```
Customer Table
-------------- 
customer_id int lastname char(5)

Orders Table
------------ 
orders_id int lastname char(5) <- to link this as foreign key to lastname in Customer table.
```

I am trying to do so but MySQL Workbench refuses to let me link datatypes of char(5) against char(5). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should check official manual for conditions when you can use foreign keys
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: Hi int, had checked before posting on StackOverFlow. I am having two columns of the same datatype (seen above), as required by MySQL.

Comment: Your problem is that `lastname` in `Customer` table is not primary key (as seen from question).
Because there can be many people with same last name it is much better to use `customer_id` as primary key and add this column to `Orders` table as foreign key.

Comment: Hey int, I gave up on Workbench and coded in SQL query instead. After some trial and error, I saw the error log was saying i need to have the two columns indexed. So that probably solved my problem.